Minkowski's inequality for $p=1$
Minkowski's inequality is usually stated for $1\leq p\leq\infty$, as follows:
Let $S$ be a measure space, let $1\leq p\leq\infty$ and let $f$ and $g$, be elements $L^p(S)$. Then, $f+g\in L^{p}(S)$ and we have the following inequality:
$$\|f+g\|_p\leq\|f\|_p+\|g\|_p, \quad \text{with  } \|f\|_p=\left[\int|f|^pd\mu\right]^{1/p}$$
However, in some texts, such as Abramowitz and Stegun "Handbook of Mathematical Functions with Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables", the inequality is stated for  $1< p\leq\infty$.
I believe the inequality holds for $p=1$, as per the triangle inequality for absolute values, but I am not sure if there are any aditional requirements I am missing. Does anyone know why the case $p=1$ is excluded in some texts?
Thanks in advance!

\| is better than ||

Maybe they exclude $p=1$, as well as $p=\infty$, to state the case of equality. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality Btw, there should be no $|$ around $f+g$ in your "Then, $|f+g|\in L^{p}(S)$".

Thanks, Anne Bauval. That's probably the case. I edited the typo out.

Minkowski's inequality is true for $1 \leq p \leq \infty$. As you mention, the case when $p=1$ is simply the triangle inequality which does not need a proof. some books treat the cases $p=1$ and $p=\infty$ separately, proof of which depends on the triangle inequality. Where, $\|f\|_{\infty}=\operatorname{ess} \sup_{x \in S} |f(x)|$ and
$$\lim_{p \to \infty} \|f\|_p =\|f\|_{\infty} .$$

Thanks for the reply!
